# Kubelet config yaml is missing when restart work node docker service

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

When I restart the docker service in work node, the logs of kubelet in master node report a no such file error.

```
# in work node
# systemctl restart docker service

# in master node
# journalctl -u kubelet
# failed to load Kubelet config file /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml, error failed to read kubelet config file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml", error: open /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have done `kubeadm reset` which cleans up all files.

Just do `kubeadm reset --force` to reset the node and then `kubeadm init` in master node and `kubeadm join` in woker node thereafter.

Answer (score 7):

Arghya is right but I would like to add some info you should be aware of:

1. You can execute `kubeadm init phase kubelet-start` to only invoke a particular step that will write the kubelet configuration file and environment file and then start the kubelet.
2. After performing a restart there is a chance that swap would re-enable. Make sure to run `swapoff -a` in order to turn it off.
3. If you encounter any token validation problems than simply run `kubeadm token create --print-join-command` and than do the join process with the provided info. Remember that tokens expire after 24 hours by default.
4. If you wish to know more about `kubeadm init phase` you can find it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init-phase/) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#instructions).

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: The command to just start the kubelet is the life saver!